# How to empty check a date field with 0000-00-00?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$array = Array(
     [FetchedData_I] => 1
     [EM_Account_V] => Test 2
     [EM_Date_D] => 2015-11-20
     [EM_Time_T] => 00:00:00
     [Channel_V] => 
     [OD_Online_Listing_ID_V] => 
     [OD_Item_Name_V] => Item Namesdsd
     [OD_Color_V] => 
     [OD_Condition_V] => 
     [OD_Qty_V] => 1
     [OD_Order_Date_D] => 0000-00-00
     [OD_Order_Time_T] => 00:00:00
     [OD_Ship_By_Date_D] => 0000-00-00
     [Comments_Internal_B] => 
 );
```

The above is the mysql data returned by a query and the scenario is to ignore the empty data and process the other data.

I'm currently using:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
   if($value!='') {
      //Process the other
   }
}
```

In the above case, how to check for the empty data of time and date like `EM_Time_T`, `OD_Order_Date_D` etc to see if they are empty?

Comment: Are you using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes i am using phpMyAdmin @rybo111

Comment: That's not empty data. That's a mere string. You do exactly the same as if you were to determine whether the value is "New Jersey".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't try to handle `0000-00-00` in PHP. Instead, fix the problem with your table.

In phpMyAdmin, edit the structure of the table and tick the `NULL` box for each date field. This means if the field is not set when inserted, it will be `NULL` instead.

Then, run the following SQL in phpMyAdmin, but change `table_name` and `field_name` as appropriate:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = NULL WHERE field_name = '0000-00-00';
```

---

To answer your PHP `foreach` question, your code should look like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if($value!='') {
      //Process the other
   }
}
```

Comment: if($val!='' || $val!='00:00:00' || $val!='0000-00-00') {
} this is what currently i am using is this a bad method ?

Comment: @Niyaz As I said, you should not be handling `0000-00-00` in PHP. You should fix the problem with the table instead. You should not have any values `0000-00-00`

Comment: I will follow your suggestion , thanks for your great time and help.

Comment: How? Reading a date - If the value is empty, the insert tries to format an empty string STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%y %H:%i') which forces empty values to be inserted as 0000/00/00 00:00 even though the field has a default of NULL